# in the ipython mode of emacs, is there a way to execute current line?

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, ipython

i can execute a highlighted region, but is there a command to execute a single line? without C-space to highlight it.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the `python.el` that comes with emacs?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `python.el` that ships with Emacs. As far as I know the mode does not define a command to execute a single line. But we can easily define a command to do so. Below is my attempt to define such a command

```lisp
(defun python-send-line ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (back-to-indentation)
    (python-shell-send-string (concat (buffer-substring-no-properties (point)
                                                                      (line-end-position)) 
                                      "\n"))))
```

If you are using `python-mode.el`, it does have a command named `py-execute-line` which according to docstring

> Send current line from beginning of indent to Python interpreter.